# Angular : get Dimension from Base64 Image

Tags: angularjs, image, size, base64, ionic-framework

I'm developping an mobile application with cordova and ionic and I would like to get the size of the image contained in a string without showing it (no img element in html). I have 2 problem, I've found a solution but with onload event and I don't use jQuery. Is there any working way with angular and ionic?

Comment: can you share your solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution :

1. Create new image
2. Set image source
3. Add event when Image is fully loaded
4. Extract size from Image loaded

   ```
   var width, height, myBase64 = "data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhDwAPAKECAAAAzMzM...........yIQAAOw==";

   var img = new Image();
   img.src = myBase64;
   img.addEventListener('load',function(){
       width=img.width;
       height=img.height;
   });
   ```

With this way you don't need to use jQuery at all. It is pure JavaScript.

Comment: In Angular mobile app, its not working. Error cant load local image